# Spring controller forwarding to another controller correctly, but view is not rendered

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, controller

I have two JSP pages with two controllers (one per JSP).

- landing.jspx is a search form, which submits via POST to the landing controller.
- appt.jspx is my second page, served by the appt controller.

I'm trying to forward from the landing jsp to the appt jsp.  I have my landing contoller marked as follows:

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("state")
@RequestMapping(value = "/landing")
public class LandingController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/postData", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String lookup(@ModelAttribute("state") State state, Model model)  {
        // something useful goes here
        return "appt";
    }
}
```

And my ApptController:

From the Spring debug logging info, I can tell that:

- My landing controller is returning and rendering appt.jspx
- I see "Forwarding to resource [/WEB-INF/jsp/appt.jspx] in InternalResourceView 'appt'"

I don't see the new page in my browser, nor do I see anything about Spring trying to match the URL to my appt controller methods in the logs.  I have to assume the appt controller never saw the request.

Here's my appt controller method (which Spring is executing):

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("state")
@RequestMapping(value="/appt")
public class ApptController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(@ModelAttribute("state") PAWState state, Model model) {

        model.addAttribute("state", state);
        return "appt";
    }
```

Using:

```
return "redirect:/appt"
```

Which gets me closer, I see:

- My landing controller is returning and rendering appt.jspx
- I see DispatcherServlet trying to match URL /appt and finding the correct method in my appt controller.
- I see the appt controller method returning the view "appt" which Spring says it Rendered

What I don't see is the new rendering in my browser.  I see the same search page.

What am I missing?

Logs (returning "redirect:/appt"):

```
12:53:40,451 DEBUG - DispatcherServlet with name 'XServlet' processing POST request for /X/landing/postData]
12:53:40,451 DEBUG - Looking up handler method for path /landing/postData
12:53:40,451 DEBUG - Returning handler method [public java.lang.String x.x.x.x.controller.LandingController.lookup(x.x.x.x.controller.valuebeans.XState,org.springframework.ui.Model) throws x.x.x.x.common.exception.XException]
12:53:40,451 DEBUG - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'LandingController'
12:53:40,732 DEBUG - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'redirect:/appt'
12:53:40,732 DEBUG - Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView: name 'redirect:/appt'; URL [/appt]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'XServlet'
12:53:40,732 DEBUG - Successfully completed request
12:53:40,732 DEBUG - DispatcherServlet with name 'XServlet' processing GET request for [/X/appt]
12:53:40,732 DEBUG - Looking up handler method for path /appt
12:53:40,732 DEBUG - Returning handler method [public java.lang.String x.x.x.x.controller.ApptController.home(x.x.x.x.controller.valuebeans.XState,org.springframework.ui.Model) throws x.x.x.x.common.exception.XException]
12:53:40,732 DEBUG - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'apptController'
12:53:40,732 DEBUG - Last-Modified value for [/X/appt] is: -1
12:53:40,732 DEBUG - Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'appt'
12:53:40,732 DEBUG - Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name 'appt'; URL [/WEB-INF/jsp/appt.jspx]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'XServlet'
12:53:40,732 DEBUG - Added model object 'org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.state' of type [org.springframework.validation.BeanPropertyBindingResult] to request in view with name 'appt'
12:53:40,732 DEBUG - Added model object 'state' of type [x.x.x.x.controller.valuebeans.XState] to request in view with name 'appt'
12:53:40,732 DEBUG - Forwarding to resource [/WEB-INF/jsp/appt.jspx] in InternalResourceView 'appt'
12:53:42,979 DEBUG - No properties file found for [file:/C:/Work/x/WEB-INF/messageSource/content_en_US] - neither plain properties nor XML
12:53:42,979 DEBUG - No properties file found for [file:/C:/Work/x/WEB-INF/messageSource/content_en] - neither plain properties nor XML
12:53:42,979 DEBUG - Loading properties [content.properties]
12:53:43,010 DEBUG - No property editor [java.lang.BooleanEditor] found for type java.lang.Boolean according to 'Editor' suffix convention
12:53:43,026 DEBUG - Successfully completed request
```

**Edit:** This is via Spring 3.1.1 using annotations

Comment: `return "redirect:/appt";` is the correct approach for redirection. It might be helpful to see your log, there may be some more useful info in there.

Comment: I've added the logs and the rest of the controller code to my original question.

Comment: I think I may be on to something... The POST request to landing controller is coming from AJAX.  We're seeing the ajax callback handler invoked, and I think this is clashing with Spring trying to do a redirect to a new jsp.  I'm thinking we may have to have the controller NOT do any forwarding/redirecting, and have the AJAX handler do it instead...

Comment: I think you are correct. If the POST was issued via AJAX, I don't believe a redirect will trigger a page reload. You would need something on your client side to trigger the page reload.

Comment: What do I need to do on the controller side then? Obviously, returning the logical name of the view isn't going to work...

Comment: Show us your JSP and how you are POSTing and we can suggest some changes there. It depends on what you are doing with the response.

Comment: I'll have to get the code in the morning, but it's JSTL & JSP.  JavaScript is used to call XMLHttpRequest using POST.  We're getting responses in the callback, but not in the finished ready state (4) status 200 variety we're looking for.   We're seeing 2 status 404 responses with the URL we're calling the servlet on, which is interesting.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what fixed our problem, but it definitely was due to the use of Ajax on the client side.  We ended up removing that and using a standard form submit and things worked fine.   I'll post more details if I get them.

Answer (score 0):

If you do return "forward:appt" instead of return "redirect:appt", things should work even with an AJAX request.  That is because a redirect results in sending an HTTP redirect status code to the client without the view being rendered before the response is terminated; whereas a forward results in the response being forwarded to the next controller and the associated view being rendered before the response is terminated.

Comment: Returning simply the name of the logical view is basically the same as a return of "forward:/appt" - in either case, using forward instead of redirect didn't work either.